# Docker container running older version of containers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have installed Docker `compose` with `apt install docker-compose` on ubuntu 18.04 server.

After installation finish, some of my Docker container has an old state and another have been deleted or are hidden (maybe?).

Why is this happening and how can I get my containers to use a the new er container version?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are running the current versions of `docker-ce` on Ubuntu by using the [information found here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). Notice the `-ce` after the word `docker`?

If your docker installation doesn't have that then it is an outdated version. In order to get the current versions you must add the repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: containerd.io is already the newest version (1.2.5-1).
containerd.io set to manually installed.
docker-ce-cli is already the newest version (5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
docker-ce-cli set to manually installed.
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

after research I found that when installing or updating docker-compose with `apt install docker-compose` it reset the default root directory of docker
my docker root directory is in a different path than the default one `/var/lib/docker`
when running `apt install docker-compose` it change my root directory to `/var/lib/docker`
I have just edit the file `docker.service` and set my previous root directory and every thing is ok now

`systemctl status docker.service` will print the location of this file at the top of the output

to edit the file follow this link https://github.com/IronicBadger/til/blob/master/docker/change-docker-root.md